# Is there a way to use just one REQUEST in Postman, using two APIs?

Tags: javascript, api, http, testing, postman

I currently have one collection in Postman, with two folders. First folder has two POST request.

1. Send a file to the server and then tests if file has been uploaded successfully with some Pre request script that changes the date and time. Here's a screenshot below:

[image: First Request]

2. Checks if the file on the first request has been uploaded in the server successfully. Using another API to make it work.

[image: Second Request]

Now, I wanna combine these both so I don't have to run two requests? Is there any way I can do that on Postman? Any help would be great! :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you make use of the `pm.sendRequest()` function inside the `Tests` tab to fire off a request to see if the file has been uploaded?

This is the example snippet you would get in the application:

```
pm.sendRequest("https://postman-echo.com/get", function (err, response) {
    console.log(response.json());
});
```

Some more usage examples can be found here: https://gist.github.com/madebysid/b57985b0649d3407a7aa9de1bd327990

Answer (score 0):

Generally calling an API requires a HTTP request. If you want to make less requests, the service you are using needs to define a special API that does both things at once.

If the service you are using does not have an API specifically for that purpose, then you will need to make 2 requests.

The question I would ask myself is: Why do I care if there are 2 requests instead of 1. And if there's a reason why that's a problem for me, is there another way I can solve that problem.

Comment: I was just trying to experiment and looking for ways to make the process shorter. I wanna put this on Nagios as well, so it's better to run just one request on newman than two, right? Is there a way I could put the second or first request on the pre-request script?